# How do I set a cookie in the selenium webdriver javascript script?

Tags: javascript, selenium, cookies, jmeter

I want to set a cookie on a simple webdriver script:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();


//WDS.driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("connect.sid", "s%3AeexeZcd_-S23Uh30e3Dmd4X9PskWF08s6m5hDurDa5Jj66SupmmiqvKEjAg6HGigl0o0V%2B9R7m4", "api." + rootdomain, "/", null));

// start test
WDS.browser.get("https://api." + rootdomain);
waitForVisible(pkg.By.linkText("Log In"));
WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.linkText("Log In")).click()
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var cookie = new org.openqa.selenium.Cookie("name","value");
WDS.browser.manage().addCookie(cookie);
```

should do the trick.

See:

- [Using Java From Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html) article to learn how to access Java SDK classes from JavaScript

  and
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for some WebDriver Sampler tips

Comment: I get the following error trying to do that: 2015/08/21 11:21:12 ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: TypeError: [jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod Options org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.manage()] has no such function "addCookie" in <eval> at line number 13

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo, it should have been `manage()`, not `manage`, the error was due to missing parentheses. I updated my answer with the correct code.

Comment: Now I am getting com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: You may only set cookies on html documents
Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds

Comment: You need to set cookie **after** `WDS.browser.get`

Comment: Now getting: 2015/08/27 10:50:46 ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: You may only set cookies on html documents
Command duration or timeout: 20 milliseconds

Comment: If you're trying to use Selenium to test REST or SOAP API - use JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler's and [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) instead as Selenium won't add a cookie for non-HTML (JSON or XML) page. See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set the cookie when the driver has started.
The driver starts when you do a .get().
Add the cookie after the .get() and it will work.